# How to have 2 very similar Excel AddIns, one for production, one for development?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-interop

It is imperative to keep the 2 Add-Ins separate.

This is what I have done:

I created 2 folders where I keep the Visual Studio files:

"Excel Production" (this one has existed for years)

"Excel Development" (this is the one I am attempting to implement properly)

I use even numbered version numbers for general deployment (1.4, 3.8, etc.) and odd numbered version numbers for development/experimental code and releases.

Naturally, the MS Solutions in the second folder are initially identical copies from the latest&greatest solution in the first folder. The next step (and the reason for this question) is: Exactly what needs to be changed in order to have two Excel Add-Ins working concurrently in the same computer (for me, and my alpha testers)?

After a lot of trial&error, this is what I have discovered:

(1) Under the "Application" section, I changed the Assembly name from "SmartQuotes" to "SmartQuotesExperimental"

(2) Under the "Publish" section I changed the "Publishing Folder Location" to point to a 2nd. publish location with the name "(Experimental)" in it.

(3) Under the "Publish | Options" section I changed:

(3a) "Description Product Name: "SmartQuotesExperimental"

(3b) "Office Settings Solution Name: "SmartQuotesExperimental"

(4) I tried to change the GID of the experimental version, but nothing changed.

What I would like to have is two Ribbon Tabs, one labeled "Quotes v1.4" and the other "Quotes v1.5".

What I have achieved with the changes described above is one Ribbon Tab, with 2 Ribbon Button groups.

I will attempt to include illustrative screenshots.

[See original post, more detailed, in an MS Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82021db1-6d9c-49de-b411-ac054fbdf806/how-to-have-2-addins-one-for-production-and-one-for-development?forum=vsto)

These 2 screenshots show the programmatic side:

[VS Fields Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rn4L.png)

[What the user sees at Excel install time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOj5O.png)

This screenshot shows what the user sees at run time:

[This is what I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFcpW.png)

This screenshot illustrates my goal:

[This is what I would like to see, inside Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/958su.png)

I use C#, if it matters.

Comment: ,..so you're asking ***"how to [create custom ribbon tabs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)"***, correct?

Comment: No, the tab that I have is generic. For some reason is the only tab accepted (it is labeled v1.4 or v1.5 depending on which version of the Add-In I installed last). I ended up with two button groups.  I need more separation: Two ribbon tabs.

Comment: In the Control Panel, I can see 2 different products: "SmartQuote" and "SmartQuotesExperimetal", which is what I want. However at Excel startup time only one of the plugins is loaded and it hosts both button groups: one for production and the other for development.

Comment: I have spent two days researching on the Internet and performing experiments. It is disappointing to see so called "experts" who instead of acknowledging their shortcomings (after all, nobody knows everything) simply resort to clicking down the post. Tragically the site(s) encourages such behavior. The question cannot possibly be clearer. This is a VERY important issue, for PROFESSIONAL developers. The Office Add-In environment is unique and has its challenges.

Comment: Every time a user criticizes the site polices, the "experts" in retaliation, click the question down, without even reading much less understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution: Stay away from the Built-In Tab Control. It gets in the way in multiple tabs scenarios.

You should select the following settings:

**Generate Member: False**

**Visible: False**

In order to avoid that pesky, well intentioned Buil-In Tab Control. Just add the tabs from the Toolbox.